# Tracing of function calls in C

Tags: c, debugging, design-patterns, trace

I'm developing some modules for an automation system written in C and I need to perform lots of work with hardware. And I see no simple way (like traditional) to debugging things instead of trace logs. So I'm looking for a good practice to log function calls. At least the sequence of calls and return values.

The way it is performed in application is quite straightforward and actually pollutes the code with irrelevant constructions like

```
int function (int param){
   if(trace_level & LOG_FCALLS){
      writelog("Entering function()");
   }

   /* something useful */

   if(trace_level & LOG_FCALLS){
      writelog("Exit from function()=%d", ret);
   }
}
```

I decided to use a macro that will do all the dirty work. Now it looks like this

```
#define LOG_E(fn) const char *__fname=fn;  printf("LOG: Entry to %s\n",__fname)
#define return(ret)     printf("LOG: Exit from %s()=%d\n",__fname,ret)

int testFunc(){
   LOG_E("testFunc");

   /*do useful things */

   return(ret);
}
```

I see the problems with this code

1. I'm overriding return statement, and it is requires to write `return(ret)` all the time instead of `return ret`. It is easy to forget this issue.
2. I'm defining string variable within my macro. I'm aware that `__func__` macro exists in C99, but my compiler, unfortunately, doesn't support this macro or any other relevant macros.
3. How to log the values of function arguments?

I'm pretty sure that it is not a new problem and I'm not the first one who faced with it. I'm also aware about AOP thing, but the code instrumentation is not acceptable solution for my system and I haven't found any possibility to do it with my compiler.

So I'm looking for a good ideas how to implement tracing in the most elegant way.

My environment:
Legacy code, C, Watcom 10.x, real-time OS

Comment: What about the fact that you don't actually return at all? i.e. your `return (ret)` is eaten up by the macro and turned into a `printf` and then the function doesn't have a return statement to execute. You're not returning in the macro.

Comment: Watcom C supports `__FUNCTION__` macro.

Comment: Just in case you tested the existence of `__func__` via `#ifdef`: It isn't a macro, but a static array (as if it were declared with `static cosnt char __func__[] = "...";` at the beginning of a function).

Comment: @ArhujShankar yep, you are right. There should be return statement

Comment: @user4419802  yes, at least google says so. But in version 11, but instead I have 10.6

Answer (score 5):

The super-serious, professional way to do this is to make a separate debug/test project, which is separate from the production code entirely. It goes like this:

- Make sure to have a backup/commit on the production code.
- Make a hard-copy of the production code on the hard drive. This will become your test project.
- Create a .txt log file where you write the full signature of each function you want to log, for example:

  ```
  int function (int param)
  float function2 (void)
  ...
  ```
- Create a little PC program/script that takes the above .txt file as input, then searches through the source code for matching lines of function definitions. The PC program will then generate a new .c file based on the original code, where it inserts the debug logging code inside the desired functions, after `{` and before `}`. It will take a few hours of your time to make such a program.
- Link your test project by using the modified source code created by your script.

The above method is how I do it myself on mission-critical software, where you have requirements from safety standards (MISRA, code coverage etc) saying that no code which is not executed in the final product is allowed.

This method ensures the integrity of the production code and guarantees that no accidental bugs are added to the program by the test/debug code. It also leaves the clutter of compile switches etc out of the production code. And you won't have any old debug code remains in your project that you forgot to delete (otherwise I *always* forget some snippet of debug code somewhere in my programs).

Comment: > hard-copy of the production code <. Wow! Have you tried SCMs like SVN, Git, Mercurial?

Comment: @myaut That would be why I said "make sure to have a backup/ _commit_". A commit is a hard-copy.

Comment: thats a great example of automation, I'll take a note.  It can be also a case, when we need a  trace log from the production system. For instance, for bugs that can be reproduced in real environment.

Comment: That is what I did for my hardware project with very limited debugger. I wrote my "Debug code inserter" program in C#. It was under 100 lines of code.

Comment: @Hooch Indeed, writing such a program shouldn't be much of a challenge for a programmer, and you can do it any language you want. Programmers sometimes forget that they are able to solve their programming problems by using programming :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#if defined(DEBUG_BUILD)
#  define START_FUNCTION if(trace_level & LOG_FCALLS){writelog("+++ %s()", __func__)
   }
#  define END_FUNCTION if(trace_level & LOG_FCALLS){writelog("--- %s()", __func__)
#elif defined (TIMING_BUILD)
#  define START_FUNCTION  WRITE_TIMED_LOG("+++")
#  define END_FUNCTION WRITE_TIMED_LOG("---")
#else
#  define START_FUNCTION
#  define END_FUNCTION
#endif
int function (int param){
   START_FUNCTION;
   ...
   if(error_occurred) {
     END_FUNCTION;
     return errror_code;
   }
   ...
   END_FUNCTION;
   return 42;
}
```

Comment: looks for me like an option. Because I don't want to break return keyword. But what is disturbing, is that we need to write `END_FUNCTION` before each return.

Answer (score 0):

This works in MS Visual C. You will need different versions of the `return` macro for different data types (or none).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRACING

#ifdef TRACING
#define LOG_E printf("Func: %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
#define LOG_R printf("Exit: %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
#define LOG_I(ival) printf("Exit: %s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, ival);

#else
#define LOG_E
#define LOG_R
#define LOG_I(ival)
#endif

int main(void){
    int retval = 0;
    LOG_E
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    LOG_I(retval)
    return retval;

}
```

Output:

```
Func: main
Hello world!
Exit: main 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You might customize your compiler to handle that. You could use [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (to customize your `gcc` compiler) if you are compiling with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/).

Maybe you might customize [openwatcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Main_Page) (or pay some *OpenWatcom* expert to do that)...

Comment: It seems like the url for MELT is no longer valid, and points to a spam site instead.